# Kanji characters from WebClient html different from actual Kanji in website

Tags: c#, html, unicode, webclient, system.net

So, I'm trying to get a portion of text from a website called [Kanji-A-Day.com](http://www.kanji-a-day.com/level1/index.php), but I have a problem.

You see, I'm trying to get the daily kanji from the website, and I was able to narrow the HTML down to what I want, but it seems the characters are different..?

[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwBYS.png)

[What it **should** look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjkVw.png)

What's even more strange is that I produced the results for the second image by copying and pasting directly from the site, so it's not a font problem.

Here's the code I use for getting the character:

```
public void UpdateDailyKanji() // Called at the initialization of a new main form
{
    string kanji;
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) // Grab the string 
        kanji = client.DownloadString("http://www.kanji-a-day.com/level4/index.php"); 
    // Trim the HTML to just the Kanji
    kanji = kanji.Remove(0, kanji.IndexOf(@"<div class=""glyph"">") + 19);
    kanji = kanji.Remove(kanji.IndexOf("</div>")-2);
    kanji = kanji.Trim();
    Text_DailyKanji.Text = kanji; // Set the Kanji
}
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? I'm guessing it's some Unicode thing but I don't know much about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That page is encoded with `charset=EUC-JP` (Encoding Japanese (EUC) CodePage 51932, HeaderName: euc-jp → Windows CodePage 932). You have to encode the resulting text accordingly and use a Font that can handle Unicode (well, that's not a problem).

Comment: So, I don't know much about Encoding but I'm assuming you're telling me to convert 'kanji' into Unicode? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Not exactly. You have to convert the resulting string, which is probably encoded as iso-8859-1 (CodePage 1252), into Japanese (EUC) unicode encoding. You can use a MemoryStream and copy to it the WebClient result, then a StreamReader to re-encode the stream bytes. I can post an example if you want.

Comment: That would be helpful for anyone who needs this question, but do you mind putting it as an answer?

Comment: Sure, no problem. Give a moment, I have to write something down, so you'll be "happy" to see that what you were trying to do is failing for absolutely no reason :)

Comment: @Jimi UEC has nothing to do with Unicode, doesn't it?

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov You mean EUC-JP? Well, it's the Japanese Extended Unix Code, quite commonly found in WebPages. In Windows it should handled with UTF-8. But the string looks more like UTF16 encoded.

Comment: Why? It's .Net. .Net `char` is UTF16LE by definition (and btw Windows uses widechars mostly, not UTF-8. It's not Linux). The author downloads EUC-JP string, it is treated as his local codepage and converted to UTF16 thus showing not what he wants.

Comment: Your answer (which I upvoted) is correct, but statements in comments are not.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov  What is not correct in the comments? Because I said "Japanese (EUC) unicode encoding"?. If this is what you're referring to, it's the Windows encoder I'm talking about, not the original multi-byte. If you're referring to the string representation, how the string is stored in memory is not related to the encoding. Can you clarify what you're referring to?. If it's not correct, I'm surely willing to re-phrase my comments.

Comment: @Jimi sure. 1) EUC-JP is not Unicode. If you meant the process of converting EUC bytes to unicode bytes, then it's not clear at all (at least for me) 2) .Net works only with one encoding: UTF16. Everything else is converted to it, and it's important.

Comment: 3) "in Windows it should (be) handled with UTF-8" it's also not clear what was meant. Why should it? Well, maybe it _should_ but Windows often thinks otherwise)

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov  Hi. About the first point (EUC-JP is not Unicode). I didn't say it. I'm referring to Japanese (EUC), the name of the Encoder (System.Text.EUCJPEncoding), [Windows CodePage 932](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_932_(Microsoft_Windows)) in `International Components for Unicode (ICU)`. 2) *.Net works only with one encoding: UTF16*. This is the [internal format representation of Unicode mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16). Not to be confused with the Encoding. Strings, more specifically, are always paired with an Encoding for representation.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov  If an encoding is not defined, the local system CodePage is used. This should not happen when the source stream is external, especially if it comes from the Web, where the de-facto standard for Unicode Code Points mapping is UTF-8. And this is how it's usually treated, unless a specific character-set (mapping) is specified (Server side or internal html Meta Tag). This is why I said that it *should be represented as UTF-8*. It should be, but it can't be assumed, because a different mapping might be specified and this has to be considered when decoding.

Comment: @Jimi ok, probably my wording was off the track. I didn't mean "you're wrong" by saying "not correct". I meant that your comments could be clearer and more reader friendly. I'm not trying to argue with you) and you have already elaborated on the meaning of your original comments

Comment: @ Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov  I don't take it as an argument, but a discussion. I do appreciate that you pointed out that my description wasn't that clear, so I have the chance to try and make a better one. And I don't assume to be a good explainer. I'm probably not. So, thanks for your remarks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you're trying to download as a string is encoded using `charset=EUC-JP`, also known as `Japanese (EUC)` (CodePage 51932). This is clearly set in the page headers.

Why is the string returned by [WebClient.DownloadString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstring) encoded using the wrong encoder?

The MSDN Docs state this:

> This method retrieves the specified resource. After it downloads the
> resource, the method uses the encoding specified in the Encoding
> property to convert the resource to a String.

Thus, you have to know beforehand what encoding will be used and specify it, setting the [WebClient.Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.encoding) property.

To verify this, check the [.NET Reference Source for the WebClient.DownloadString](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs,882) method:

```
try {
    WebRequest request;
    byte [] data = DownloadDataInternal(address, out request);
    string stringData = GetStringUsingEncoding(request, data);
    if(Logging.On)Logging.Exit(Logging.Web, this, "DownloadString", stringData);
    return stringData;
    } finally {
        CompleteWebClientState();
    }
```

The encoding is set using the **Request** settings, not the **Response** ones.
The result is, the downloaded string is encoded using the default CodePage.

What you can do now is:

- Download the page twice, the first time to check whether the WebClient encoding and the Html page encoding don't match.
- Re-encode the string with the correct encoding, set in the underlying WebResponse.
- Don't use WebClient, use HttpClient or WebRequest directly. Or, if you like this tool, create a custom WebClient class to handle the WebRequest/WebResponse in a more direct way.

This is a method to perform the re-encoding task:
The string returned by WebClient is converted to a Byte Array and passed to a `MemoryStream`, then re-encoded using a `StreamReader` with the Encoding retrieved from the `Content-Type: charset` Response Header.

**EDIT:**
Now using `Reflection` to get the page `Encoding` from the underlying `HttpWebResponse`. This should avoid errors in parsing the original `CharacterSet` as defined by the remote response.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

public string WebClient_DownLoadString(Uri uri)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        // If Windows 7 - Windows Server 2008 R2
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        client.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache);
        client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "ext/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.KeepAlive, "keep-alive");

        string result = client.DownloadString(uri);

        var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)client.GetType().GetField("m_WebResponse", flags).GetValue(client))
        {
            var pageEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(wc_response.CharacterSet);
            byte[] bytes = client.Encoding.GetBytes(result);
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms, pageEncoding))
            {
                ms.Position = 0;
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            };
        };
    }
}
```

Now your code should get the Japanese characters in their correct form.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.kanji-a-day.com/level4/index.php", UriKind.Absolute);
string kanji = WebClient_DownLoadString(uri);

kanji = kanji.Remove(0, kanji.IndexOf("<div class=\"glyph\">") + 19);
kanji = kanji.Remove(kanji.IndexOf("</div>")-2);
kanji = kanji.Trim();

Text_DailyKanji.Text = kanji;
```

Comment: Sorry if you're getting tired of me, but it doesn't appear to work. Granted, I haven't done much reverse engineering with your code yet to figure out how it works due to it being so late here so I'll have to get back to you tomorrow to try and diagnose the problem myself. Don't worry for now. (Also, if you're curious the level 1 kanji shows up as a big dot now).

Comment: Of course I've tested this code before posting it. See that the font you're using can handle this character set. Segoe UI and Arial can. When you're available again, ping me and we'll work this out.

Comment: @IIRawCodeII  Try to implement this method exactly how it is, so we're on the same page if something is not working as expected. See also the edit, since I've modified the code a little in the meanwhile.

Comment: Okay, so it appears to be working now? I did not change the code from yesterday so I have no idea what was the cause but it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: @IIRawCodeII I'm glad you made it. However, see the edit. I've made a couple of changes that should ensure a better "understanding" of the original encoding.