# Getting ? as replacement for characters æ,ø,å,é etc. even when setting UTF8 encoding

Tags: c#, html, webclient

I've got the following snip of code where i download a html page.

I've tried a couple of variations where i set UTF8 encoding after downloadstring aswell. What am i doing wrong?

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    var page = webClient.DownloadString("http://replacementurl.com");
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: If you're printing non ASCII characters to console, you get a `?`. The character is still the same in memory.

Comment: WebClient uses the Default Encoding (Local CodePage) if not instructed otherwise. If you define an Encoding, you have to be sure that you're using the right one (the same the Html page uses). See if this can help: [Kanji characters from WebClient html different from actual Kanji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49846392/kanji-characters-from-webclient-html-different-from-actual-kanji-in-website?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)

According to the documentation Encoding lets you set the [code page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/470fd72s(v=vs.110).aspx).  But for me that that returns and exception.

This works for me:

```
Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding(true, true);
string value = "\u00C6 \u00D8 \u00C0 \u00C1 \u00C2";

try
{
    byte[] bytes = enc.GetBytes(value);
    foreach (var byt in bytes)
        Debug.Write(String.Format("{0:X2} ", byt));
    Debug.WriteLine("");

    string value2 = enc.GetString(bytes);
    Debug.WriteLine(value2);
}
catch (EncoderFallbackException e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Unable to encode {0} at index {1}",
                        e.IsUnknownSurrogate() ?
                            String.Format("U+{0:X4} U+{1:X4}",
                                        Convert.ToUInt16(e.CharUnknownHigh),
                                        Convert.ToUInt16(e.CharUnknownLow)) :
                            String.Format("U+{0:X4}",
                                        Convert.ToUInt16(e.CharUnknown)),
                        e.Index);
}
```

Appears you cannot assign the code page.  Odd.