# Unable to get non english characters from webpage source using vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.5

I used the provided block of below code many times to get the source of the webpage which worked always in my cases.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
Dim wc As New WebClient
wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
Dim Source As String = wc.DownloadString("https://www.rp.pl/")
```

This code is not getting the Polish characters with the used `Encoding`. I have tried the other available `Encoding` also with no luck. Like in the page, there is a heading "Rafał Trzaskowski kontra TVP. Chce sprostowania", but after getting the source by the above code snippet, it is showing "Rafa� Trzaskowski kontra TVP. Chce sprostowania".

Can anyone please help me to correct my code so that i get the page source exactly?

Comment: I tried by writing the `Source` to a text file also with no luck!

Comment: are you sure the encoding is utf8?

Comment: I am not sure, but i am using this. How can i be sure?

Comment: I've written some notes on the `WebClient` behaviour in relation to the Encoding [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49846392/kanji-characters-from-webclient-html-different-from-actual-kanji-in-website?answertab=active#tab-top). If you need a translation/summary in this question, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply a matter of looking at what encoding does the webpage use and matching it.

```
wc.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1250)
```

And it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted outputting the Polish character, to ensure that the problem does not lie in the console's limitations? Alternatively save the "Source" variable in a txt file to view in notepad. It is possible that the string contains the correct value but fails to display. At least this is a problem I have faced in the past