# WebClient.DownloadString() method returns special characters

Tags: c#, asp.net

My application is an `asp.net` application. To make it very simple I have `one.aspx` which simply writes hello. This works fine when executed in the `URL`.

Now I have `two.aspx` and have the following code :

```
   string downloadurl = String.Format(@"http://{0}", rawUrl.Authority + "1.aspx");
            using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
                webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
                result = webClient.DownloadString(downloadurl);

            }
            contentpage.InnerHtml = result;
```

The code essentially downloads the `1.aspx` output in the `html` format.

This is where I get an error. The result is a set of some special characters, instead of the output Hello. I tried `UTF-8` and `ASCII`, but nothing seems to work.

**Output**

> "\u001f‹\b\0\0\0\0\0\u0004\0\u008dQMo‚@\u0010½7é\u007fØì\u000fp\u0001ÓX\u0012h\u0003tK=P\"\u0010´^\f”]Ùò±
>   ‹Â¿\u0017Ô\u0003¦\u0017ç2y3ïeÞÌh”\u001f\nP\u0010‘òD‡\u0015o\u0004\u0004Ñ¯`¼Ôá\f…ŒœV-iF<‹šª{ß³DW$\t‚!ÃQ+Ã·ç'\u008d•U+€è+¢Ã”%\t)!(£b@»]¸Äk?0\u0002|\u0015Ý\u0015ŽQÞ\u000e¤Ø¢Õb^ÒÂWPM‰›Õ‹ìäl~\u000eY­vv@×fÊ\u009dîC„|³RLc»ì1yÁ'yî\u0004–ºíë¿8u£žºÔD¼ñ¼\u0018QjÕ’-ûÞ^‡\0\r\u000e\u001fõhãoì\u0019\u0081ëý3;éÜ\«’õùª(êu\u0002¸…–°ã\u0004ŽñEòœO\u0018èž2*.ÓÄpiø¸VCã\u0003.Ë\u009d\u0001LM4oÇ\u0001\0\0"

Comment: Why did you set the Encoding to `Encoding.ASCII`? Setting the Header while downloading a web page is useless (to `Latin-1`?). Read the notes here: [Kanji characters from WebClient html different from actual Kanji in website](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49848091/7444103)

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `downloadurl`? Please don't guess, check in the `Watch window`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the content type and utf format

https://dotnetfiddle.net/eIdm1D

Comment: updated. please refer the question. i still get the same error

Comment: Have you tryed utf16