# How to fix strange symbols when web scraping

Tags: c#, encoding

Basically, I'm pulling information from a website, specifically one with Hebrew littered throughout the page. Getting the Hebrew properly is quite important to the program, but instead of getting the Hebrew characters, I am getting strange accented English characters.

I've tried Encoding.Convert but it hasn't worked, I've tried changing the encoding, but that is just given me ???? symbols. I've tried writing it to a txt file to see if it was the cmd that was not able to display it; I still got the same symbols.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
       string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("https://www.pealim.com/dict/");

       Console.WriteLine(htmlCode); 
 }
```

Comment: Se the notes/sample code here: [Kanji characters from WebClient html different from actual Kanji in website](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49848091/7444103)

Comment: You can see that WebClient uses the WebRequest Encoding, not the WebResponse one. So, you do what you can usually do with HttpWebRequest: get the actual encoding from the HttpWebResponse instead. You can then decode the string using the actual encoding. Which not necessarily is UTF-8. A number of https resources still use a Local/specific encoding (go figure).

Comment: Btw, if you have a Console app, `Courier New` can print Hebrew symbols.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) and not WebClient.  It is more recent and handles encoding issues.

However, `https://www.pealim.com/dict/` returns the page as UTF-8 so encoding is not an issue!  I suspect your console is displaying the Hebrew incorrectly; see [this article](https://superuser.com/questions/257333/hebrew-utf8-characters-in-windows-cmd-console).

One way to verify that you are receiving the correct text, is to set a break point on your `Console.WriteLine` and then inspect the text in the debugger.

If you plan on **scraping** the pages, [html-agility-pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) is very useful.