# How to download https file from nseindia.com?

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I have tried with the following code.The error received is "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive".

System OS: Windows 7 Home Basic SP1
.net Version: 4.5.2

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;

namespace wc_downloadfile
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

            using(WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                string src = "https://nseindia.com/content/indices/ind_nifty50list.csv";
                string dest = @"C:\temp\N50.csv";
                try
                {
                    var ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36";
                    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, ua);

                    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "*/*");
                    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");

                    wc.DownloadFile(src, dest);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to download file  --- " + e.Message);
                }

            }
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove this: `wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");` or make a custom WebClient, get the HttpWebRequest and set `[HttpWebRequest].AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;` (or use WebRequest/HttpClient directly)

Comment: @Jimi. Thank You. You comment was valuable regarding Encoding. However that doesn't solve the problem. The user agent "Chrome/61.0.3163.100" was causing the issue.

Comment: Yes, that can happen. If the Browser version you're passing in the headers supports [HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), sometimes a website enables this feature and waits for *interaction*, WebRequest doesn't support it. As a suggestion, if you need to just download a file, use the IE11 header: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident / 7.0; rv: 11.0) like Gecko"`. It doesn't trigger any `advanced feature` :)

Comment: About the *Encoding*: this is not about encoding, its about the compression algorithm. But, there might also be a problem with the encoding, since WebClient uses the default encoding is none is specified. If you have encoding problems (your text looks garbled), see the notes here: [Kanji characters from WebClient html different from actual Kanji in website](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49848091/7444103) to use the encoding of the WebResponse.

Answer (score 0):

Modified the user agent value and the problem got resolved. Following is the working code.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;

namespace wc_downloadfile
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

            using(WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                string src = "https://nseindia.com/content/indices/ind_nifty50list.csv";
                string dest = @"C:\temp\N50.csv";
                try
                {
                    //Removed Chrome/61.0.3163.100
                    var ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/537.36";
                    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, ua);

                    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "*/*");

                    wc.DownloadFile(src, dest);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to download file  --- " + e.Message);
                }

            }
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the comment on the question. You're using a *wrong/unofficial*  header, so your User-Agent is kind of *unknown/undefined*. These are the actual Chrome headers: [The latest user agent for Chrome](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/chrome).

Answer (score -2):

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)");
        Stream stream = client.OpenRead("https://nseindia.com/content/indices/ind_nifty50list.csv");
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        String content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Can you add some description of how this code solves the problem?

Comment: @Pratap Deshmukh. Thank You. With the reference of the user-agent in your answer, I was able to be resolve the issue.