# How to get a file from Pastebin.com and saving the file on computer in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

How to get a file from the Pastebin.com and the save the file to the system. In the interface there is a textbox, where a user can paste a link to a pastebin file `https://pastebin.com/raw/*a-random-code*`, there will be a button to start fetching the file, once the program fetches the file, the file is saved on to the computer as a `downloadedtext.txt` file.

Comment: Check [this](https://pastebin.com/api#14) and [this](https://pastebin.com/hU6AjetH)

Comment: Thank you @JQSOFT, but I do not understand C#

Comment: Just create a new [System.Net.WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8) and use it to download the raw paste: `TextBox1.Text = wc.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/target-paste-key")` and dispose the WebClient once the download completes `wc.Dispose()`

Comment: @JQSOFT  ...and now you'll have to explain why you can only read a Paste when the Encoding matches the local one :)

Comment: @Jimi uhhaa you got me partner. That should be another post. :) OR as usual save my ... you know :) Happy new year buddy.

Comment: @JQSOFT (You don't have to explain anything, actually :) [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49848091/7444103) there's a description of what WebClient does (which also, in a way, explains its intended use - download *stuff* from known remote resources). You can 1) Hope that a remote resource uses UTF8 and set the WebClient.Encoding accordingly 2) Derive a custom WebClient, get the WebResponse encoding and use it to decode the (string) resource 3) Use reflection, as shown in that sample code. Happy `new[] { 0x07E4 }` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternate method very easy.

```
Private Sub frm1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim filename As String
    filename = "C:\Users\sample.txt"
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("https://pastebin.com/raw/*enter code*", filename)
End Sub
```