# How to display every kind of character on the form

Tags: vb.net, character-encoding, special-characters

I'm working with vb.net trying to display character's and symbols like "" or ' or è à ì & etc.

I am downloading songs from a url with an async download, I grab their filename with webclient download string, and those names sometimes contains special chars/symbols.
Is there any way to "normalize"/encode them to finally diplay the complete name?

I did read it s matter of encoding, but how can I encode a string that Im not going to know which kind of special chars it got?
Is there any universal encoding that display ALL known chars and symbols in the world?

Thanks

EDIT1:
I'm using the following code:

```
Dim x As New WebClient()
        x.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 

        Dim source As String = x.DownloadString(TextBox1.Text.Replace(" - YouTube", ""))  'GETTING FILENAME FROM YOUTUBE LINK
        Dim title As String = Regex.Match(source, "\<title\b[^>]*\>\s*(?<Title>[\s\S]*?)\</title\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups("Title").Value
        Dim a As String = title.Replace(" - YouTube", "")
        Dim webdecode As String = WebUtility.Htmldecode(a)
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(webdecode.tostring + Environment.NewLine)
        
        Label13.Text = webdecode
```

A test link can be ANY youtube video. In this case I'm stucked with `
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_-sVTewqXk
Thanks

Comment: Read the notes here: [Kanji characters from WebClient html different from actual Kanji in website](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49848091/7444103)

Comment: Oh I see, but I dont really understand c#, so I converted your code and It still seems unclear  to me. Cant I just encode the string to make it easier? I've also tried unsuccessfully with a regex following the example online.

Comment: It's a simple matter: WebClient uses the Encoding set with it's `Encoding` property. If none is specified, `Encoding.Default` (the local encoding) is used. This encoding is mostly useless, unless it matches the HTML page encoding (usually UTF-8) or it uses similar code points in the lower plane (corresponding to the ASCII sub set). So, if you **really** want to use WebClient, you have to read the Encoding specified in the underlying WebResponse (what WebClient uses under the hood), and re-encode the HTML page you downloaded with the correct Encoding. **DON'T USE ANY REGEX**.

Comment: You can also try to set `Encoding.UTF8`, since most HTML pages are encoded like this. But you have no guarantee that it'll work. If you read that question, that Web Site encodes the HTML pages using one of more common Japanese encoding (since it shows Kanji), but of course UTF8 will fail to decode those code points, since those are all different in the two encodings and will return something else completely.

Comment: Hi Jimi, I simply solved with Webclient.encoding= encoding.utf8!, but now I sow a problem with  **- "** it shows **&quot**...

Comment: See [WebUtility.HtmlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmldecode). BTW, you should post your code and, possibly, an URL to test.

Comment: I tried but I'm not able to decode this sample text: &amp;quot;BIANCO/GOSPEL&amp;quot;
The code I'm using is 
 Dim sampleText As String = "&amp;quot;BIANCO/GOSPEL&amp;quot;"
        Dim webDecoded As String = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(sampleText)
           MsgBox(webdecoded)
I've tried also with httputility.htmldecode or httputility urlencode but still I'm getting the same simple text without encoding..

Comment: If you don't provide code and nothing to test this code on, there isn't much else to go on with. BTW, that string is not valid HTML, the escaped symbols are also inverted.

Comment: To make it simple, I create a fresh project with the code I just posted on the previous comment. 
To make also easier for you to help me, The original code I'm using in the main project is : https://pastebin.com/H9JVtYsE

Comment: Oh I see, sorry about that. I just edited my post here.

Comment: You cannot download and parse a HTML page like that. If you want to extract some parts of the **rendered** HTML, use a WebBrowser Control and use its methods (e.g., `[Document].GetElementsByTagName`, `[Document].GetElementById` etc.) or use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/), which is of course available as a NuGet Package.

Comment: Hi Jimi, still thanks for your replies. What you mean I cant parse a html page like this? I m just extracting the title of the link through webclient which I think is more reliable and fast than using a Webbrowser control. I tried again the code I used and cant explain why, but it's working like I wanted.

Comment: All right, if all you need is the Title of the HTML page, than it's ok. I've tested your code with the URL you posted and the result set in `webdecode` is `GEMITAIZ/MACE - "BIANCO/GOSPEL"`

Comment: That's perfect, exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks for your time, again :)

Comment: BTW, you can change your Regex in just `"<title>(.*?)\s*.\s*YouTube\s*<"` and take `Group(1)` so you don't need to replace the suffix after and it's a little safer.

Comment: Somewhere in the programming language you are using is a function to encode text for a URL.  In PHP, it is `urlencode()`.  Use the function.